# Buffer data retrieved in loop and print at end

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, printf, snmp

I have a function to retrieve some SNMP data and print it.

The function slows down for each record printed and with a lot of routers and walks, it's very very slow. I figure it will be much more efficient to fetch all the data and print it once done, but I'm wondering how to achieve this in bash.

My question is simple, how can I make this function faster?

```
function primary_cpe_hsrp_snmp(){
    echo
    read -p "Do you REALLY want to check HSRP info from the CPEs? [y/N] " -n 2 -r
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
            snmp_community="<somecommunitystring>"
            for cpe in "${pricpes[@]}"
            do
                    hostname=$(snmpget -v 2c -c $snmp_community $cpe sysName.0 | sed -e 's/^SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: //g')
                    printf "\nSome HSRP information for $hostname on IP $cpe\n"
                    printf "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-12s \n" " ___________________________________________________________________________________"
                    printf "| %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-12s | \n" "Virtual IP" "Active IP" "Standby IP" "State"
                    printf "| %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-12s | \n" "____________________" "____________________" "____________________" "____________"
                    while read -r line; do
                            ifHsrpState[$i]=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c $snmp_community $cpe 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.15.$line | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')
                            ifHsrpActiv[$i]=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c $snmp_community $cpe 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.13.$line | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')
                            ifHsrpStand[$i]=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c $snmp_community $cpe 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.14.$line | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')
                            ifHsrpVirip[$i]=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c $snmp_community $cpe 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.11.$line | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')
                            printf "| %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-12s |\n" "${ifHsrpVirip[$i]}" "${ifHsrpActiv[$i]}" "${ifHsrpStand[$i]}" "${ifHsrpState[$i]}"
                    done <<< "$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c $snmp_community $cpe CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpAuth | sed 's/CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpAuth*\.//' | awk -F" " '{print $1}')"
            printf "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-12s \n" " ___________________________________________________________________________________"
            done
    else
            :
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt at refactoring the code.

The idea is to reduce the number of `snmpwalk` calls to **one per IP**, then use `awk` to parse and extract the data of interest from the output.

The shell still does the final formatting (instead of `awk`) because you were using bash arrays and I don't know what you want to do with the data afterwards.

The new `primary_cpe_hsrp_snmp` function now takes at least two arguments: The **SNMP community** and the **IP address(es)** of the CISCO hardware to connect to. I also moved the user interaction outside of the function (it felt wrong to keep it there).

<sub>**edit:** modified the `OFS` of `awk` and the `IFS` of `read` from white-space to comma.</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# function primary_cpe_hsrp_snmp SNMP_COMMINUTY [IPADDRESS ...]
#
primary_cpe_hsrp_snmp() {

    local snmp_community="$1"
    local cpe

    for cpe in "${@:2}"
    do
        local hostname="$(snmpget -v 2c -c "$snmp_community" "$cpe" sysName.0 | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}')"

        printf 'Some HSRP information for %s on IP %s\n' "$hostname" "$cpe"
        printf ' ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— \n'
        printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-12s |\n' "Virtual IP" "Active IP" "Standby IP" "State"
        printf '| ———————————————————— | ———————————————————— | ———————————————————— | ———————————— |\n'

        local ifHsrpVirip ifHsrpActiv ifHsrpStand ifHsrpState

        while IFS=',' read ifHsrpVirip ifHsrpActiv ifHsrpStand ifHsrpState
        do
            printf '| %-20s | %-20s | %-20s | %-12s |\n' "$ifHsrpVirip" "$ifHsrpActiv" "$ifHsrpStand" "$ifHsrpState"
        done < <(
            snmpwalk -v 2c -c "$snmp_community" "$cpe" .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1 |
            awk -v OFS=',' '
                /cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr/ {
                    key = substr($1,index($1,"."))
                    cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr[key] = $NF
                    next
                }
                /cHsrpGrpActiveRouter/ {
                    key = substr($1,index($1,"."))
                    cHsrpGrpActiveRouter[key] = $NF
                    next
                }
                /cHsrpGrpStandbyRouter/ {
                    key = substr($1,index($1,"."))
                    cHsrpGrpStandbyRouter[key] = $NF
                    next
                }
                /cHsrpGrpStandbyState/ {
                    key = substr($1,index($1,"."))
                    cHsrpGrpStandbyState[key] = $NF
                    next
                }
                END {
                    for (key in cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr)
                        print cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr[key], cHsrpGrpActiveRouter[key], cHsrpGrpStandbyRouter[key], cHsrpGrpStandbyState[key]
                }
            '
        )
    done
}

################################################################################

pricpes=(
    someIP_1
    someIP_2
    ...
)

read -r -p "Do you REALLY want to check HSRP info from the CPEs? [y/N] " -n 1 
echo
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    primary_cpe_hsrp_snmp '<somecommunitystring>' "${pricpes[@]}"
fi
```

<sup>**remark:** you may want to try `snmpbulkwalk` instead of `snmpwalk`; it might speed up the requests.</sup>

---

###### Explanations

In your code, for each pair of `SNMP interface ID` **`.`** `HSRP group number` (represented by `X.Y` in the table), you were querying the following OIDs/MIBs:

| OID | MIB |
| --- | --- |
| 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.11.X.Y | CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr.X.Y |
| 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.13.X.Y | CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpActiveRouter.X.Y |
| 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.14.X.Y | CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpStandbyRouter.X.Y |
| 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1.15.X.Y | CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpStandbyState.X.Y |

I have to say, firing so many forks and initiating so many TCP connections will surely make the code inefficient.

In fact, you can get the HSRP data for **all** pairs of `SNMP interface ID` **`.`** `HSRP group number` with a single `snmpwalk` call by requesting the `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1` OID (aka `CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpEntry`). The downside is that the output won't be ordered by `SNMP interface ID` **`.`** `HSRP group number` and that you'll get superfluous information, so you'll have to filter/select/order the data that you need by post-processing the output (that's what the `awk` does in my solution).

Now, let's take a line "of interest" from the output of `snmpwalk … 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.106.1.2.1.1` for explaining the `awk`, for example:

```
CISCO-HSRP-MIB::cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr.2.1 = IpAddress: 2.3.4.5
```

In the `awk` code, this line satisfies the condition `/cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr/` (which is a regex match), so its corresponding block of code is executed:

```rb
/cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr/ {
    key = substr($1,index($1,"."))
    cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr[key] = $NF
    next
}
```

- The `key = substr($1,index($1,"."))` extracts `.2.1` from the **first field** and saves it as `key`
- The `cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr[key] = $NF` stores the **last field** (`$NF`), whose value is `2.3.4.5`, in the associative array `cHsrpGrpVirtualIpAddr` for the key `.2.1`.
- The `next` means that we're done with this line so we can go on with the next one.

The others `condition { ... }` are similar except the `END` one which is executed after all the input lines were processed. In it I loop over all the defined keys and output the values stored in the arrays in a format that can be easily `read` with the shell.

Comment: Great answer. AWK is efficient and it helped me realize it was the actual snmpwalk to some various devices that was variously slow.Would you mind commenting the AWK bit for top marks?

Comment: @AndyThompson I had made the awk quite straightforward on purpose, at least I thought it was; I added some explanations now ;-)

Comment: It is quite straightforward but you know SO loves the added comments :) Thanks! Just waiting out the time limit before I can complete the bounty. Wish you a nice weekend.